# Using PowerPoint VBA to open CSV file in Excel

Tags: excel, csv, powerpoint

I am trying to write a PowerPoint VB application which needs to display certain values from a text file in a fixed format.

When I (manually) open that text file as a csv file in Excel, I get the required values in fixed cells and I know how continue from there by VBA.

What I do not know is how to create the Excel spreadsheet using a macro in PowerPoint.
Also, I want to make sure that the parameters for opening the file (using space as delimiter; multiple spaces count as one) are defined in the macro so that I do not have to rely on current local settings.

Thanks in advance for any idea or reference.

Comment: There's lots of info on the web about automating Excel from PPT or any other application. Assuming you want to do that, go into PPT's VBA IDE and look for help on the Workbooks.Open method.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm203082)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue

Comment: Thank you Steve Rindsberg, eventually I parsed the text file and extracted the required data without using Excel. Storing the extracted data in another Excel file is straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

1. use ~.OpenText 
   it Supports consecutive delimiter

2.Use text file not with .csv but with .txt extension
  Excel fails to load a text with other delimiter if it's extension is '.csv'

Following macro reads a text file with delimiters of space character and copies the Excel table to Powerpoint Table on a Slide.

Full code:

```
Sub ReadCSV()

Dim xlsApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlsWb As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlsSht As Object        'Excel.Worksheet
Dim rng As Object           'Excel.Range
Dim Target As String

On Error GoTo Oops
'Set xlsApp = New Excel.Application
Set xlsApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlsApp.Visible = True

Target = ActivePresentation.Path & "\test_space.txt"

'Below don't support consecutive delimiters
'Set xlsWb = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Target, Format:=3)

'File Extension .CSV won't work here. .TXT works.
xlsApp.Workbooks.OpenText FileName:=Target, Origin:=2, StartRow:=1, _
    DataType:=1, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Space:=True, Local:=True
Set xlsWb = xlsApp.ActiveWorkbook
Set xlsSht = xlsWb.Worksheets(1)

Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim tbl As Table
Dim numRow As Long, numCol As Long
Dim r As Long, c As Long

Set rng = xlsSht.UsedRange
    numRow = rng.Rows.Count
    numCol = rng.Columns.Count

With ActivePresentation
    Set sld = .Slides.Add(.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
End With
Set shp = sld.Shapes.AddTable(numRow, numCol, 100, 100, 200, 150)
shp.Name = "Table"
Set tbl = shp.Table

'Copy cell values from Excel Table to Powerpoint Table
For r = 1 To numRow
    For c = 1 To numCol
        tbl.Cell(r, c).Borders(ppBorderBottom).ForeColor.RGB = rgbBlack
        With tbl.Cell(r, c).Shape.TextFrame
            If r > 1 Then .Parent.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rgbWhite
            .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
            .TextRange = rng.Cells(r, c)
            .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter
        End With
    Next c
Next r

xlsWb.Close False

Oops:
If Err.Number Then MsgBox Err.Description
'If Excel App remains in the system process, Excel App won't respond and run again.
If Not xlsApp Is Nothing Then xlsApp.Quit: Set xlsApp = Nothing

End Sub
```